# You could fit a city bus in the length of the awkward pause

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does it mean that the pause was very long?

> “Elsie, listen. We get it. You take as much time as you need.  You
> have plenty of vacation days, sick days, personal time saved  up,” he
> says, trying to be helpful.
>
> “How much my-husband-died time do I have?” I ask, trying  to lighten
> to mood, trying to make this okay for everyone. But  it’s not okay for
> everyone, and the joke lands like a belly flop.  **You could fit a city
> bus in the length of the awkward pause  between us**.

Taylor Jenkins Reid "Forever, Interrupted"

Comment: Very short answer - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among road vehicles, buses are longer than most. The speaker is saying that the pause was appreciably longer than a normal one.

[image]